How to set document.hidden to always return false?
I have a very specific need for some websites to always "believe" that their tab is active (as you'll see from the code below, it's mostly Google Maps and iCloud), equivalent to Chrome DevTools -> Rendering -> Emulate a focused page.
So far, changing a tab after the page has been loaded has been a success, but I need to refresh some tabs in the background using an extension - and those tabs return true for document.hidden, of course.
So far I've been looking for visibilitychange event and stopped propagating it, but since document.hidden is true on page load (in background), it doesn't matter. The HTML page I used as a test displays the results - if I load it in an active tab, it shows up as active and doesn't change the status; however, if I reload it using an auto-refresh extension, it shows as hidden.
I'm fairly new to extension development (though, thanks to this website I'm already using about half a dozen of my own extensions). Here is my test page:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Visibility test</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre id="logger">
</pre>
<script>
var preContent = document.getElementById('logger').innerHTML;
var ts = new Date().toISOString();
if (document.hidden) {
    preContent = preContent + ts + " hidden" + "\n";
} else {
    preContent = preContent + ts + " visible" + "\n";
}
document.getElementById('logger').innerHTML = preContent;
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
    var preContent = document.getElementById('logger').innerHTML;
    var ts = new Date().toISOString();
    if (document.hidden) {
        preContent = preContent + ts + " hidden" + "\n";
    } else {
        preContent = preContent + ts + " visible" + "\n";
    }
    document.getElementById('logger').innerHTML = preContent;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

My extension:
manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Always visible",
    "description": "BytE Always visible",
    "version": "1.4",
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*/*"
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "webRequest"
    ],

    "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": [
            "*://*.google.com/*",
            "*://*.icloud.com/*",
            "*://127.0.0.1/*"
        ]
    },
      
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://*.google.com/maps/*",
                "*://*.icloud.com/*",
                "*://127.0.0.1/*"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_start",
            "js": [
                "inject.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": ["injected.js"],
            "matches": ["*://*.google.com/*","*://*.icloud.com/*","*://127.0.0.1/*"]
        }
    ]
}

inject.js
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('injected.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);

injected.js
for (event_name of ["visibilitychange", "webkitvisibilitychange", "blur"]) {
  window.addEventListener(event_name, function(event) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }, true);
}


No extension can do that

@JaromandaX Could you please elaborate? We can catch the events, but cannot change document.* properties? I would gladly accept your answer.

It's not an answer. the events are informative, not something you can prevent - docs say "The event is not cancelable."

@JaromandaX Could you please elaborate which docs say that, and what event are they referring to? As you can see, I have no problems with catching a visibilitychange event in a Chrome Extension.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event

@JaromandaX That is the page that I used when I created the test script and the cross-browser extension. I think you misunderstood my question. I can, of course, catch the visibilitychange event, but I want document.hidden to be false on page/document load.

Oh, sorry ... I thought you were trying to cancel the event ... of course event.stopImmediatePropagation(); won't do anything anyway, since the event doesn't propagate anyway, and the event is fired because the visibility has changed, therefore anything you do in a handler won't change the fact that visibility has changed ... see my first comment, no extension, no javascript, can do what you want to do. document.hidden is a read only property that can't be hacked

@JaromandaX Sorry, but actually, event.stopImmediatePropagation on visibilitychange does stop most of the scripts that rely on page being in focus. I'm just having trouble with the two websites I mentioned because they read the document.hidden upon page load and I use an Auto-reload extension for them. :) Thank you for you effort!

Oh, right. Sorry. I thought your intent was to stop document.hidden from changing, you just want to stop the visibility event from propagating - I totally misread your question

I mean, your title state quite clearly How to set document.hidden to always return false? so that's what I am saying is impossible- so, I guess I didn't misread it, you mis-wrote it

It's possible and actually quite trivial: all you need is to run your script in the MAIN world at document_start as shown here and use Object.defineProperty on document.

@JaromandaX Right, it was a misundestanding. I don't want to change any additional events, I just want it to always return false - hence the misunderstanding.

Simply run your script in the MAIN world at document_start as shown here and use Object.defineProperty to override document.hidden.

Remove web_accessible_resources
Remove inject.js
Use injected.js and add "world": "MAIN" in content_scripts

// manifest.json
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [.........],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "js": ["injected.js"]
    "world": "MAIN"
  }],

// injected.js
(() => {
  Object.defineProperty(Document.prototype, 'hidden', {get: () => false});
  
  for (const n of ['visibilitychange', 'webkitvisibilitychange', 'blur']) {
    window.addEventListener(n, stopEvent, true);
  }

  function stopEvent(evt) {
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
    evt.stopPropagation();
  }
})();

